# Decompressing Image BLOB from DB using Inflator

Tags: java, spring, blob

Playing around with uploading Images to a MySQL database using a BLOB.  No issue uploading the images (small and large) however when trying to retrieve said Image (using simple REST API/postman etc.) my server hangs.

```
  public static byte[] decompressImage(byte[] data) throws DataFormatException, IOException {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] tmp = new byte[data.length];

        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(tmp);
            outputStream.write(tmp, 0, count);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Tried uploading a variety of images, but only the large ones seem to hang.  No errors just seems to go into an infinite loop in the code block below:

```
        while (!inflater.finished()) {
            int count = inflater.inflate(tmp);
            outputStream.write(tmp, 0, count);
        }
```

Basically for some reason, inflater.finished() remains false for large images.

Comment: I think your memory is low. Try to use `java.sql.Blob` to stream the bytes.